# Access MVC's model property from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following model which is wrapped in my view model i want to 
pass `MaximumDaysAheadBookable` property to datepicker function

```
public class SessionObject
{    
    public int MaximumNumberOfRooms { get; set; }
    public int MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom { get; set; }
    public int MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom { get; set; }
    public int MaximumDaysAheadBookable { get; set; }
    public int MaximumDaysBetweenCheckinCheckout { get; set; }
}
```

How do I access one of the above properties from Javascript.js file ?  then pass it to datepicker function :

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
   $("#Arrival").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:MaximumDaysAheadBookable , ////here i want to pass model value 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "img/ui_cal_icon.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",

    });
 });
```

Comment: Server side (razor) code is not parsed in external files. You need to declare it in the main view (e.g. `var maxDate = @Model.MaximumDaysAheadBookable;` and then in the external file - `maxDate: maxDate,`

Comment: There has to be a duplicate

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is what i want correctly , thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a external js file you will need to pass the data as a parameter.